# Include graphic after the third line in a paragraph

Tags: graphics, floats, wrapfigure

I want to include graphics inside a paragraph right after the *n*-th line.

(It would be best if it could work with `wrapfig` or `floatflt`)

Is there a simple way to it? Or maybe there is a package which helps to do such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to do with the `insbox` plain TeX macro package, which defines an `\InsertBoxL` and an `\InsertBoxR` commands, with two arguments: the number of lines at the beginning of the next paragraph which will *not* be shortened, and the contents to be inserted afterwards. In addition, an optional argument – the number of supplementary lines to be shortened in case TeX doesn't compute the correct number of lines.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\InsertBoxL{3}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pepe-le-pew2}\\[1.5ex]\footnotesize Pepe le Pew in action\end{tabular}\enspace}[3]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. strange that wrapfig does not provide such an option...

Comment: If the paragraph goes to the next page, then it does not solve the problem (you get graphics at the very bottom of the first and empty box on the next page). Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  You can try with anegative value for the optional argument. Could you post  an example code?